# 404 Not Found [IP: ...]

Tags: flatpak

```
Obj:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu hirsute InRelease     
Obj:8 http://co.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu hirsute Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

I run the command `sudo apt-get update`, and I get this. Can it generate future problems for me, or does it have any implication? And if it has an implication, how can I solve it, I use Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 1):

On latest Ubuntu you really do not need [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ealexlarsson/+archive/ubuntu/flatpak) to have Flatpak support.

So you have to disable the PPA by

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
```

and then install `flatpak` package from [default official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/flatpak):

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flatpak
```